# Send Physical keystrokes to the keyboard on emulator or real device

Tags: applications, adb, keyboard, android-emulator, automation

I need a way to press a key on an Android Keyboard ( irrespective of its language). For example, if the keyboard is in English and I press the "q" key it should type "q" but when the keyboard is in French it should show "a" (Because Keyboard is "QUERTY" and French is "AZERTY".

I have been through the google android docs here, which state that this should be possible: https://source.android.com/devices/input/keyboard-devices#notes

> The Android key code associated with common alphanumeric and symbolic
> keys may vary based on the keyboard layout and language. For
> historical reasons, the physical scan codes and HID usages associated
> with keys on a keyboard are often defined positionally even though the
> labels printed on those keys may vary from one language to another.
>
> On a US English (QWERTY) keyboard, the top-left alphabetic key is
> labeled Q. On a French (AZERTY) keyboard, the key in the same position
> is labeled A. Despite the label, on both keyboards the top-left
> alphabetic key is referred to using the HID usage 0x07 0x0014 which is
> mapped to the Linux key code KEY_Q.
>
> When Android is configured with a US English keyboard layout, then the
> Linux key code KEY_Q will be mapped to the Android key code KEYCODE_Q
> and will produce the characters 'Q' and 'q'. However, when Android is
> configured with a French keyboard layout, then the Linux key code
> KEY_Q will be mapped to the Android key code KEYCODE_A and will
> produce the characters 'A' and 'a'.
>
> The Android key code typically reflects the language-specific
> interpretation of the key, so a different Android key code may be used
> for different languages.

I have tried using ADB sendEvent function as well using the following command:

```
adb shell su 0 sendevent /dev/input/event12 1 30 1. // type a
adb shell su 0 sendevent /dev/input/event12 0 0 0. // press key
adb shell su 0 sendevent /dev/input/event12 1 30 0. // clear buffer
adb shell su 0 sendevent /dev/input/event12 0 0 0   // release key
```

But this too types "a" in both English and French Keyboard.

Is there a function/tool I can use to accomplish my task?

Comment: Have you tried to use `adb input text ..` or `adb input keyevent ..` instead ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/8483797/150978

Comment: Ya same issue using those as well @Robert